# Multiple order by in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to order my products in category page by average rating (DESC) and then by price (ASC).

```
| id  |  avgrating   |   price   |
|  1  |      4       |     10    |
|  2  |      4       |      5    |
|  3  |      5       |      7    |
```

Order: 3, 2, 1.

So I tried with:

```
$args['meta_key'] = '_wc_average_rating';
$args['orderby']  = array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
    'price' => 'ASC',
);
```

But they aren't ordered (also) by price. I also replaced `price` with `_price`, same result.

I'm using latest version of WordPress (4.8) and WooCommerce (3.0.8).

**Edit:**

If I use:

```
$args['meta_key'] = '_wc_average_rating';
$args['orderby']  = array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
    'ID'             => 'DESC',
);
```

Order works as excepted, DESC by average rating and then DESC by ID. So, I have to change `ID` with `price` but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check by passing the `order` with arguments

Check with these,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'sort_by_type' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num title';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'sort_by_type';

    }

    if ( '_wc_average_rating' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num title';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_wc_average_rating';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, returns: 3, 2, 1. I think it's default order or something like this...

Comment: both are different conditions or you want both combined? Also list the order here as well (you need 2,1,3)?

Comment: Order with `_wc_average_rating` is 3, 2, 1. With `sort_by_type` returns 0 products.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to order product first by date then out of stock items be at the end. I tried the below code. but doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
$orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
if ( 'sort_by_date' == $orderby_value ) {
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';
$args['meta_key'] = 'sort_by_date';

}
if ( '_stock_status' == $orderby_value ) {
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
 $args['order'] = 'DESC';
$args['meta_key'] = '_stock_status';
}
 return $args;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31664607)